# Overriding a method of a Java class in Nashorn JavaScript

Tags: java, vert.x, nashorn

The following **Java method** creates a JavaMail password authenticator with fixed username and password:

```
public static Authenticator createJavamailPasswordAuthenticator(String username,String password) {
    final String usernameTmp = username;
    final String passwordTmp = password;
    return new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(usernameTmp,passwordTmp);
        }
    };
}
```

I need to write a **Nashorn JavaScript function** that does exactly the same, but I don't know how to override the Authenticator's getPasswordAuthentication Java method. Being a Nashorn greenhorn, I tried the following

```
function createJavamailPasswordAuthenticator(username,password){
    var authenticator=new javax.mail.Authenticator();
    authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication=function(){
        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
    }
    return authenticator;
}
```

...but that didn't work.

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here:

```
return new Authenticator() {
```

creates an anonymous inner class! In other words: you are creating a new class implicitly, and instantiating an object of that class. Your new class is extending the class it derives from, therefore you can override methods in the { block }.

The simple solution would be to make that *explicit*: create a "real" java class that takes username, passsword as constructor parameters, and that uses them as you do in your first example. Then simply have the java script code instantiate *that* class and pass the required arguments.

Don't mimic an implementation detail, instead focus on what needs to be done (creating an object of a class that has specific behavior)!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm aware that I could create a separate class for this. The static Java method above is part of my own utility class, but I wanted to know if the same thing could be achieved in Nashorn JavaScript or not.

Comment: You have to understand the fundamental difference here. The java code gets compiled, and you end up with that anonymous class existing as class in your classpath. At runtime, this is more less just that: using same class, instantiating it. You are asking how to "dynamically" create a java class from your javascript code at runtime. Those things aren't similar, they are really different!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I take this as a definite "No, what you want can not be achieved with Nashorn JavaScript".

Comment: @xpages-noob Not necessarily definite ;-) ... I am not an expert in JS, and what the Nashorn engine can do. But: it would really really surprise me if that engine is able to create Java classes on the fly like this. I rather doubt that. But simply wait some more time before accepting my answer, maybe some Nashorn-domain-expert comes in and has shows how it could be done ;-)